# How do I detect a link tag with no href?

Tags: jquery

Strangely, some people like to create `<a>` tags without hrefs and that's tripping up a section of my project. Here is what I have so far:

```
        iframe.find("a").not("a[href*='#'], a[href*='%'], a[href*='javascript:;']").bind("click", function() {

            NProgress.start();

            $("button.active .tab-title").html(currentTitle);
            $("button.active .tab-favicon").attr("src", getFavicon);

            var _location = $(this)[0].href;
            $("iframe.active").attr("src", _location);

            console.log("Hmm, " + _location);

        });
```

I have a progress bar that shows the loading of the link clicked. Of course, if there's no href/source, it chokes. How do I detect an `<a>` with no source? Adding `a` to the `.not` section doesn't work because then my loading bar won't work.

Comment: Why would you want a loading bar when you're not loading anything anyway?  I don't know why you wouldn't just exclude these links with your selector.

Comment: The loading bar only activates on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
    if ($(this).attr("href").length == 0) {
       alert("no href for this link");
       return false;
    }
```

or if you want to only target links with an `href`

```
if ($(this).attr("href").length > 0) {  }
```

Comment: The first section of your answer works for me. I have those other conditionals in my code above, because although they have sources, they don't go anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery and checking if attribute is empty :

```
 if ($(this).attr('href') != '') { // if no href }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check `this.href`. It will be an empty string if the attribute is empty or isn't present.

Answer (score 0):

```
var hrefattr = $(this).attr("href");
if(hrefattr != ' '){
    //your code here
}
```

get the value of  tag only with href and store in a variable, if it is not empty that means you have got the tag with href attribute.

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: taken your advice, i make sure i'l explain the ans i provide :) thanks